# Groovy - no signature of method after inserting a method

Tags: groovy, metaprogramming, metaclass

Well, I'm getting MissingMethodException even after inserting a method into a metaclass. It's strange that its says there's no signature applicable for a String, but there's for java.lang.Object
Some obs:

1. - yeah, the `List<Class> classes` that I'm iterating contains the class I'm trying to use
2. - please don't suggest me to use @Log4j or any other, it's not working with any method I try to insert (even though I can manipulate the same class fields with reflections)
3. - as I said, the stackstrace says that there isn't signature `(java.lang.String)` but there's to `(java.lang.Object)`

```
        classes.each { clazz ->
            clazz.metaClass.log = { instance.simpleLogger.log(it) }
            clazz.metaClass.debug = { instance.simpleLogger.debug(it) }
```

```
    @Override
    void enable() {
        debug("eae meu bom")
    }
```

```
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: com.dont.testplugin.Terminal.debug() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [eae meu bom]
Possible solutions: debug(), debug(java.lang.Object), getAt(java.lang.String), log(), dump(), log(java.lang.Object)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.unwrap(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:56) ~[?:?]
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaClassSite.java:78) ~[?:?]
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:49) ~[?:?]
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:133) ~[?:?]
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:141) ~[?:?]
```

Comment: probably you are using it in a static way. please show the line where you calling debug method.

Answer (score 1):

Echoing @daggett here, with the assumption that you are calling the debug method from groovy (and not java) and that the place you are calling it from is not annotated with something like `@CompileStatic` I would have expected that to work as well.

The following code:

```
class Foo {}
Foo.class.metaClass.debug = { println("debug: $it") }

def f = new Foo()
f.debug("eae meu bom")
```

when executed prints:

```
─➤ groovy solution.groovy
debug: eae meu bom
```

(Groovy Version: 3.0.6 JVM: 11.0.9.1)

I think we need more context to get you relevant answers.

Comment: i'm not calling it statically. Apparently when I specify the Class `Foo.class.metaClass.debug = { instance.simpleLogger.debug(it) }`.it works, but iterating the `List<Class>` doesn't.

Comment: Could you post a representative code sample exhibiting the behavior?

Answer (score 1):

For future readers:
I really don't what's happening. I solved changing from

```
classes.each { clazz ->
clazz.metaClass.method = {methodHere}
}
```

to

```
classes.each { clazz ->
Instance instance = generateInstance(clazz)
instance.metaClass.method = {methodHere}
}
```

I was already instantiating it, so wasn't a problem to me to change it, don't know for you future readers.